# Set Binding.Converter in code

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

How can i set the Converter used for a DataBinding in the code of a C# Application (cannot use XAML, because my Converter has no parameterless constructor, and those parameters are needed to do the conversion).

**EDIT:**
Another solution which worked for me in this case was:

```
Application.Current.Resources["MyConverter"].MyProperty = MyProperteryValue;
```

Comment: Why not set those parameters *after* construction?

Comment: @H.B.: I tried, but those values got ignored. It seems like it always constructed a new converter..

Comment: @H.B.: Seems it does work now, my error before was, that i provided 2 constructors, one of them parameterless, and then overwrote the object in the resource dictionary with one constructed with the 1-parameter constructor. But the Binding still used the old object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `BindingOperations.GetBinding(someInstance, SomeDependencyProperty).Converter`.

Comment: Ah, thanks, seems i chose the wrong words when googling. Aside from that, its quite cumbersome, that you cant access the Binding objects using Methods/Properties of the objects which are actually participated in the Binding, but trough a unrelated 3rd class.

Comment: @smerlin: You can also write `instance.GetBindingExpression(Property).Parent`.  If you want to, you can also make an extension method.